# Adding more than one app to Facebook fan page

Tags: php, facebook

I have created this fan page http://www.facebook.com/pages/ohlala/327385737341 and added an application on tab "Special Offers". I just wanted to know if it is possible to add more than one app to the fan page? Can't see any option like I did for the first app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether an app can be added as a tab is a setting of the application, so not all can be added (app developer can choose separately for User profiles and fan pages, as well). Once you've chosen 'Add to page' for an application, those that can be added as tabs will appear when you click the + sign on your page.